# Unittest assertion error and encoding

Tags: python, unit-testing, encoding, flask, assert

I'm trying to write a simple test for my flask app. The app is in cyrillic.

```
def test_empty(self):
    res = self.app.get('/')
    assert 'В базе нет ссылок.' in res.data
```

When I try to run this test, I get

```
FAIL: test_empty (__main__.LinkTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 17, in test_empty
    assert 'ðÆ ð▒ð░ðÀðÁ ð¢ðÁÐé ÐüÐüÐïð╗ð¥ð║.' in res.data
AssertionError
```

Seems like there's a problem with encoding.

Could someone please explain me the nature of this problem?

I'm using python **2.7.3** on **Windows 7**.

Comment: You are using a byte string, and the contents will depend entirely on how you saved the source code. You generally want to *avoid* using bytestrings when handling text, use Unicode strings instead. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Another possibility is that your *console* is misinterpreting the bytes in that line when Python echoed the source code line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, I've tried to use both `unicode(str)` and `u'str'` with no success. I also have a `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in my source file.

Comment: The `coding` line helps, provided you actually used that codec to save the file (but it'll be harder to produce something that can still be interpreted as UTF-8 and not throw an exception). If `u'...'` doesn't help here, then it is your *console* that is misconfigured. UTF-8 data is printed but the console interprets the bytes in a different codec.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've just tried to log another cyrillic string from different chunk of code, and yes, you are right, there's something wrong with my console. But how can this "visual bug" affect the test result? How does assertion depend on console encoding?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hm, also tried to echo cyrillic string from golang source saved as utf-8 and it works fine. So, this problem is related to python, not console.

Comment: So what does `print repr('В базе нет ссылок.')` produce? Note: no `u`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81387/discussion-between-fakemeta-and-martijn-pieters).